# Using JS to apply Hue-Rotation, Saturation, and Lightness Filters at the same time

Tags: javascript, css, filter

I'm trying to get the colour of an image to change from Red to a specific other colour with CSS filters through Javascript.  That way the user can select which colour they want and it'll change the colour of the image to that colour.  I can get the button to change, Hue-Rotation, Saturation, or Lightness, but not all at once.

How do I make a function that sets all three at once?

What I have at the moment:

```
function OrdReset() {
document.getElementById("Ordinary").style.webkitFilter = "hue-rotate(0deg) saturation(0%) lightness(100%)";
}
```

Comment: Just use varibles intead ! Like hue-rotate(rotate(adeg) ......

Comment: I can't find a lightness filter. Is it brightness?

Answer (score 0):

Woops! Apparently, calling Saturate(%) "Saturation(%)", and Brightness(%) "Lightness(%)" breaks your code.

Comment: You can check this sort of thing in your browser's dev tools inspect facility - if the value of a CSS property is invalid it will show you - normally with a little yellow triangle - when you look at the element.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.